# Can't compile JUnit test java class: cannot find symbol SeleniumUtil

Tags: java, selenium, junit

I had some working JUnit tests (that weren't unit tests, they were front end tests) which used Selenium.

Now, we want to integrate Selenium with Zephyr which requires being able to run those same tests via a BAT file - via the command-line.

I have the following files in my project src/test/java:

- ScreenshotTestRule.java - rule to take snapshot on test failures
- SeleniumUtil.java - framework for invoking/resetting selenium
- TestSeleniumUtil.java -  checks that selenium can open borwsers.
- TestJVSUserLogins.java - checks login accounts
- TestSubjectAttributes.java - checks subject attributes after login

Now, I was able to compile SeleniumUtil.java into SeleniumUtil.class simply by doing "javac SeleniumUtil.java". That worked. I got the class file.

But I have been utterly failing at compiling the other classes!

```
C:\diss-jvs-ui-junit-selenium\src\test\java\mil\osd\dmdc\diss\jvs\selenium>javac TestSeleniumUtil.java
TestSeleniumUtil.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
        static SeleniumUtil seleniumUtil = null;
               ^
  symbol:   class SeleniumUtil
  location: class TestSeleniumUtil
TestSeleniumUtil.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
```

Now to me, SeleniumUtil is compiled - so why doesn't javac understand what this object is?

I know there's a lot I'm missing here. I've always used Java inside of Eclipse, or just done JSPs... I haven't been in this situation before in my meager 1.5 year's experience with java (.5 of which was in 1998).

I've been messing around with classpath a lot, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you miss the SeleniumUtil on your classpath. When compiling code using javac, you need to add the dependencies using the `-classpath` option.

However, I think you have a bigger issue. I wouldn't recommend compiling by hand using 'javac'. Use Maven or Gradle instead, or possibly even Eclipse (not recommended for real projects).

Comment: What I need to do is have a .BAT file that runs *each* separate JUnit java file.  So I'm not sure how using Maven or Gradle would help, but in part that's because I've never used Gradle and only barely used Maven outside of eclipse. The end result is I need a BAT file to run the Unit test.

Comment: Why do you need a bat file? Why won't `mvn test` or `gradle test` do? Or put those commands in a bat file. I'm suggesting to use those tools since they help you manage the classpath.

Comment: I get what you're saying though. I'm going to try that.

Comment: I need a bat file because cross-integrating silenium with zephyr and jira requires being able to run unit tests via command-line, which is a bat file.  That's how Zephyr gets the results to give to ZBot to give to JIRA. In theory.

Comment: Basically, I can run them in Eclipse, but that's not how they will be run.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I'm not trying to sell anything here, or trying to be smart: it's easy to use Maven or Gradle, especially the latter, since you'll need minimal configuration to get it to work.

Comment: Okay... Had to mess with my m2 a bit, but yes, mvn worked and compiled all my classes! Thanks Erik Pragt!

Comment: Sure no problem! Glad I could help! And sorry for suggesting Maven as a solution ;-)